# Activar/Desactivar menú programáticamente con MetisMenu y jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

El `li` que tiene id "idPrimeraLista" tiene su atributo de clase de valor "active", que abre la lista, y al modificar el valor a "inactive" se cierra. 
Intente cerrar la lista al modificar la Clase a "inactive"con jQuery a través del click de un botón, pero no me funciona, quisiera saber cuál es la causa o el error.

(El desplegar la lista y la clase mencionada pertenece a un plugin adjunto MetisMenu)

```js
$(function() {
  $('#auto-collapse-menu-demo').metisMenu();
});
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#boton").click(function() {
    $("#btnModificable").removeClass("btn-success");
    $("#btnModificable").addClass("btn-primary");
    //************************************
    $("#idPrimeraLista").removeClass("active");
    $("#idPrimeraLista").addClass("inactive");
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/metisMenu/2.7.1/metisMenu.js"></script>

<input id="boton" type="button" value="MODIFICAR"><br><br>
<button id="btnModificable" class="btn-success">Boton</button>
<ul id="auto-collapse-menu-demo">
  <li id="idPrimeraLista" class="active">
    <a href="#">Abrir</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Primero</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Segundo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Tercero</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: El planteamiento del problema y lo que quieres lograr no es claro.

Comment: Amigo estas seguro de que solo con cambiar la clase debe de ocultarse? por que puede que el plugin tenga un proceso que ademas de agregar la clasde inactive hace otros movimientos. Hay que revisar eso antes pues el código se ve bien.

Comment: Dos detalles: el menú no se cierra al cambiar el valor de la clase a "inactive" sino cuando se quita la clase "active", y como te dice otro usuario, algunos valores en el enlace y la sublista cambian al abrir/cerrar el menú. Antes de intentar cambiar el comportamiento del plugin te familiarices con su funcionamiento abriendo la consola de desarrollador, inspeccionando los elementos relacionados y abriendo y cerrando el menú para ver qué sucede.

Comment: Te recomiendo que leas [ask] donde encontrarás consejos para mejorar tus publicaciones, y que completes el [tour] para ver cómo funciona el sitio de forma general (y así ganar tu primera medalla).